# Java convert class from Java 14 to 1.7

Tags: java

I know usually people do this the other way around, but how do I convert the following class to from Java 14 to Java 1.7.

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

/**
 * Creates Jwt token and other util methods.
 */
public class JwtTokenUtil {

    private String SECRET_KEY = "secret-876123";

    public String extractUserName(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(SECRET_KEY).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    /**
     * Pass in user details, and get a Jwt
     * @param userDetails
     * @return
     */
    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String,Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, userDetails.getUsername());
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String,Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10)) // 10 hrs
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, SECRET_KEY).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validteToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUserName(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }
}
```

There are compilation errors on:

- the lambda expressions: `Claims::getSubject` and
  `Claims::getExpiration`.
- the following import does not exist in Java 1.7: `import java.util.function.Function;`

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own implementation of `Function` and replace the method references with implementations of newly created `Function` interface, but I'm guessing you have to convert much more than a single class, so I recommend [Retrolambda](https://github.com/luontola/retrolambda).